# How to append leading zeroes to an NSString?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen multiple answers but those have converted an integer into a string and so on.

I have an NSString and want to add leading zeroes to it.

```
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2X",abc];
```

add zeroes to hexString if its length is less than 3 and return another string. Appreciate help.

Comment: Why add zeros to `hexString` after the fact? Why not add the zeros when you create `hexString` to being with?

Comment: How can I add zeroes while I am creating the string? Can you please post the code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to convert the `int` value `abc` into a 3-digit hex value with leading zeros to ensure it uses 3 digits, then do:

```
NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03X", abc];
```

Comment: I am under impression that %2x converts into hex, how come single "x" is doing the same. Thank you for the answer, Can you please help me understand.

Comment: The `X` mean convert to hex. The `3` means that you want three hex digits. The `0` means to pad the result with sufficient zeros that you get three digits (without the zero the result will be padded with spaces to gives three characters). `%2x` would give a hex taking two digits, padded with a space if needed.

Comment: Thank you, maddy, so if I want to convert a number into hex and add 4 leading zeroes if the length of converted hex str is less than 4, then I need something like %04x, just to clarify. Awesome explanation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Experiment. Try different formats. Look at the documentation for the `NSString stringWithFormat` method. There are links that take you to the full specification of the possible format specifiers.

Comment: @rmaddy spot the difference here `0xff` and `0xFF` and guess what is x and X for :) happy coding.